# How to extract the values assigned to x from this string?

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I am trying to create a regex that I can use to extract out the values assigned to variable x in the following string:

> `(req.idf=6ca9a AND (req.ster=201 OR req.ster=st_home) AND (req.ste=hi OR req.ster=hijst_iuer OR ((req.ster=laHome OR req.ster=laHome_Jtre) AND (tax=IN OR taxIP=MX))) AND NOT ((x=u259 AND (x=66438 OR x=5423)) OR x=9853))AND(NOT x=28743)`

I am trying to get the output in the following format, by getting the numerical values assigned to the variable x: 66438, 5423, 9853, 28743

So far, I have tried creating regex like: `(x=[^)]+)` and `\bx=([^)]+)\b`, but I am unable to get the desired output.

I will be using this in my query in Redshift using `regexp_substr` function.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why your attempts target `s` rather than `x`?

Comment: @3limin4t0r, sorry I just edited the question to include x in my regex.

Comment: Do you need to match all values or just the numerical ones?

Comment: [`\bx=\K\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/Qhw7VS/1)

Comment: @jhnc, thanks, this works perfectly fine when i use it here for testing - https://regex101.com/.

But I would be using it in my redshift query using regexp_substr here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html
I can see that \b and \K are not supported :( - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions-posix.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fifth argument of [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html) enables the usage of [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions):

> *parameters*
>
> One or more string literals that indicate how the function matches the pattern. The possible values are the following:
>
> [...]
>
> - p – Interpret the pattern with Perl Compatible Regular Expression (PCRE) dialect.

This regular expression will allow you to use a positive lookbehind to get what you want:

```
(?<=(\s|\()x=)\d+
```

I've added a preceding '(' or ' ' in case your string is somewhat mutable, but it shouldn't be necessary for your example.

You can check it [here](https://regexr.com/7d135).

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I tried executing the query:

`select regexp_substr(columnName, '(?<=(\s|\()x=)\d+', 'p' ) from tableName where id = 3;`

I am getting this error: 
`[22P02] ERROR: Invalid input syntax for integer: "p"`

Comment: You need to provide the arguments 3rd and 4th too: `select regexp_substr(columnName, '(?<=(\s|\()x=)\d+', 1, 1, 'p' ) from tableName where id = 3;`

Comment: Bear in mind that REGEXP_SUBSTR will only return one of the occurrences. In this case it will be the 1st one, as indicated by the 4th argument.

Comment: thanks!, I am able to retrieve the first value, is there any other way, I can use this to retrieve all the values, or this is simply not possible in Redshift, and I will have to collect all the records in a list and do a programmatic parsing.

Comment: Are you going to have always the same number of **x** variables?

Comment: No, it can be variable.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function test(regex,str){
        let temp=regex.exec(str)?.at(1)??false; //first match is to prevent unwanted coma and if no matches, then returns value after ??'
        while(m=regex.exec(str)?.at(1)){temp+=`, ${m}`;} //iterate every matches; use ?.at(1) instead of [1] to prevent TypeError then if no match You will get falsy check
        return temp;
        }
    
    console.log(test(/\bx=([\d]+)\b/g,
         "(req.idf=6ca9a AND (req.ster=201 OR req.ster=st_home) AND (req.ste=hi OR req.ster=hijst_iuer OR ((req.ster=laHome OR req.ster=laHome_Jtre) AND (tax=IN OR taxIP=MX))) AND NOT ((x=u259 AND (x=66438 OR x=5423)) OR x=9853))AND(NOT x=28743)"))
```

You will have to iterate over matches.

```
 function test(regex,str){
    let temp=regex.exec(str)?.at(1)??false; //first match is to prevent unwanted coma and if no matches, then returns value after ??'
    while(m=regex.exec(str)?.at(1)){temp+=`, ${m}`;} //iterate every matches; use ?.at(1) instead of [1] to prevent TypeError then if no match You will get falsy check
    return temp;
    }

test( /\bx=([\d]+)\b/g,
     "(req.idf=6ca9a AND (req.ster=201 OR req.ster=st_home) AND (req.ste=hi OR req.ster=hijst_iuer OR ((req.ster=laHome OR req.ster=laHome_Jtre) AND (tax=IN OR taxIP=MX))) AND NOT ((x=u259 AND (x=66438 OR x=5423)) OR x=9853))AND(NOT x=28743)")
```

Jus run my code snippet :)

Comment: thanks !, since i will be including the regex in my sql query, I won't be able to use this.

Comment: You could mention that :)
Anyway i gave You quite clear regexp.
I suggest to write more about problem.